# How to mannage refs in react

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

This below code is to create svg shapes via React components.
Explanation of the code : I am doing composition in the react components first I have a parent **g** node and after that I have a child **g** node and in each child **g** node i have svg **path**.
what i am doing is : i am creating the shape and after that i am transforming that shape.

i have to transform the each shape individual the problem is that if we do this using the state of the parent it will work fine for the last element but what about is we want to change the transformation of the first element i.e we want to resize the shape

```js
      var ParentGroupThread = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
          return {
            path: {}
          };
        },
        render: function() {
          Interfaces.DrawingThreads.ParentGroupThread = this;
          var totalDrawing = Object.keys(this.state.path).length;
          var drawings = [];
          var pathState = this.state.path;
          for (var i = 0; i < totalDrawing; i++) {
            Interfaces.DrawingThreads.ParentThreadRef = pathState[i].ParentThreadId;
            Interfaces.DrawingThreads.ThreadRef = pathState[i].threadIdPath;
            drawings.push(React.createElement(ParentThread, {
              ParentThreadId: pathState[i].ParentThreadId,
              threadIdPath: pathState[i].threadIdPath,
              d: pathState[i].d,
              fillPath: pathState[i].fillPath,
              strokePath: pathState[i].strokePath,
              storkeWidthPath: pathState[i].storkeWidthPath,
              classNamePath: pathState[i].classNamePath,
              dataActionPath: pathState[i].dataActionPath,
              dash: pathState[i].dash
            }));
          }
          return React.createElement('g', {
            id: 'ParentGroupThread',
            key: 'ParentGroupThread_Key'
          }, drawings);
        }
      });

      var ParentThread = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
          return {
            transformation: ''
          };
        },
        render: function() {
          Interfaces.DrawingThreads.ParentThread[Interfaces.DrawingThreads.ParentThreadRef] = this;
          return React.createElement('g', {
              id: this.props.ParentThreadId,
              key: this.props.ParentThreadId + '_Key',
              ref: this.props.ParentThreadId
            },
            React.createElement(Thread, {
              threadIdPath: this.props.threadIdPath,
              key: this.props.threadIdPath + '_Key',
              d: this.props.d,
              fillPath: this.props.fillPath,
              strokePath: this.props.strokePath,
              storkeWidthPath: this.props.storkeWidthPath,
              transformPath: this.props.transformPath,
              classNamePath: this.props.classNamePath,
              dataActionPath: this.props.dataActionPath,
              transformation: this.state.transformation,
              dash: this.props.dash

            })
          );
        }
      });
      var Thread = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
          return {
            transformation: ''
          };
        },
        render: function() {
          Interfaces.DrawingThreads.Thread[Interfaces.DrawingThreads.ThreadRef] = this;
          return React.createElement('path', {
            id: this.props.threadIdPath,
            d: this.props.d,
            fill: this.props.fillPath,
            stroke: this.props.strokePath,
            strokeWidth: this.props.storkeWidthPath,
            className: this.props.classNamePath,
            'data-action': 'pathhover',
            strokeDasharray: this.props.dash,
            vectorEffect: 'non-scaling-stroke',
            transformation: this.state.transformation,
            ref: this.props.threadIdPath
          });
        }
      });

      ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(ParentGroupThread), document.getElementById('threads'));
```

Comment: I think you can improve the question a little, so that people can help you better.

Comment: please do a favour by giving me the idea what explanation is needed

Comment: I think its unclear about the relationship with the transforms of parent and what you are doing and why. Its all a bit vague and the code doesn't really help. Maybe some sort of logic/pseudo code would help describe what actually the problem is.